# I tried to align 2 identical boxes with border using negative margin but it's off by a little

Tags: html, css

I tried to make 2 boxes with the same dimension, padding, and border align on one another, but it's off by a bit. They aren't perfectly on top of the other one.
Then, I tried the same thing but without borders. Turns out, they align perfectly.

[before, without borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArqaI.png)

[after, without borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9JZ5.png)

[before, with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfsTb.png)

[after, with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE4EF.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html {
        padding: 0rem;
        margin: 0rem;
        border: 0rem;
        }

        .one {
            margin: -0rem;
            margin-bottom: -0rem;
            }

        .two {
            margin: -0rem;
            margin-top: -10rem;
        }
            
        .container p {
          width: 10rem;
          height: 10rem;
          border: 0.1rem solid blue;
          background-color: ;
        }

        .container p:last-of-type {
            background-color: ;
        }


         div{
         margin: 10 rem; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <p class="one">paragraph one.</p>
      <p class="two">paragraph two.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Borders have width. With borders, you must subtract the width of the border in addition to the height of the element in order to place them directly on top of each other using negative margin.

Comment: just use flex for that instead of all this CSS lines

Comment: Investigate box-sizing border-box. Also please check through the CSS you provided which has some typos, and add HTML so we can run it for ourselves - the version with absolute positioning would be good to see for example (if that is how you are doing it).

Comment: try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to each one.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean suggested, you have to take borders into account. `.two` is moved down not only by `.one`'s height, but by the sum of its top and bottom border. Which means that the top margin should be sum of `-10rem` (height) `-0.1rem` (top border) `-0.1rem` (bottom border) = `-10.2rem`.

Answer:

```css
      .two {
        margin: -10.2rem 0 0;
      }
```

---

The second suggested solution also works - to add `box-sizing: border-box;`:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Here it is added to all elements in the document, which is a kind of usual way to do it. You can also try adding it only to paragraphs - put `box-sizing: border-box;` into `.container p {`, which also was in the comments.